# Very few executors are running on the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a lab environment of cdh5 with 6 nodes-node[1-6] and node7 as the nameNode. 
node[1-5]: 8gb ram, 2 cores
node[6]: 32gb ram, 8 cores
I am new to spark and I am trying to simply count the number of lines in our data. I have uploaded the data on hdfs (5.3GB).
When I submit my spark job, it only runs 2 executors and I can see its splitting the task into 161 task (there are 161 files in the dir).

In the code,  I am reading all the files and doing the count on them.

```
data_raw = sc.textFile(path) 
print data_raw.count()
```

On CLI: spark-submit --master yarn-client file_name.py --num-executors 6 --executor-cores 1

It should run with 6 executors with 1 task running on them. But I only see 2 executors running. I am not able to figure the cause for it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to submit the job is:
spark-submit --num-executors 6 --executor-cores 1 --master yarn-client file_name.py 
Now its showing all the other executors.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect only 2 nodes are running spark. Go to cloudera manager -> clusters -> spark -> instances to confirm.

Comment: All the nodes are running. Also, if I run any mapreduce job on YARN, all the nodes are fired to process that job. The issue is coming with spark only.